# Is there an erlang term parser written in ruby?

Tags: ruby, erlang

We have a logging system, and erlang OTP server is writing logs in erlang term.

We also have Rails interface for internal users, and I want to provide a log analysis for them.

I have tried to find an erlang term parser, not erlang parser, written in ruby. but no luck yet.

erlang terms are simple; atom, tuple, list(including string), binary, and pid/ref

atom is like a symbol

tuple is like a hash

list is like an array

binary/pid/ref are like string

Anyone knows any existing erl-to-ruby parser?

Comment: Do you mean a *parser* as in a lexer and syntactic analyzer to build the abstract syntax tree of an erlang program or a *translator* from erlang to Ruby?

Comment: No, I meant just a translator from erlang term(not erlang program) to ruby. just like a json parser.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this isn't quite what you're looking for, but you could check out [BERT-RPC](http://bert-rpc.org/). It has serializers, clients, and servers for various languages, including Ruby (they are listed at the bottom of the page).

Comment: I would recommend BERT and ERNIE, written by Tom Preston-Werner of github. Inaka (my consultancy) used this for a significant Rails/Erlang project and it worked very well. It allows conversion between Erlang terms and Ruby. It has about things like Boolean, etc, that you have to be comfortable with, but I agree w/this recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

BERT is new, and it seems overkill to me, and I don't see code out-there for this purpose,
I made my own.

https://github.com/bighostkim/erl_to_ruby

Answer (score 0):

This module from the people at basho seems to be exactly what you need.

https://github.com/basho/erlang_template_helper